# Is there any relationship between matrix and transposed matrix vector multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

my question may seem particularly broad, but I was curious whether there was any particualar field or application where there exists a relationship between $A$ $*$ $v$ and  $A^T*$ $v$, with $A$ being a $n$-square matrix and $v \in R^n$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which kind of relationship are you expecting to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example is if $A$ is a rotation, then $A^T$ is the inverse rotation. You can the  choose whatever relationship you have between the vectors. For example $Av=x$ and $A^Tv=y$, then $x\cdot v=y\cdot v$. Or $A^2y=x$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I'm hopefully waiting for other ideas before accepting your answer